# Set ImageView from real path

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have the real path of an image which I am retrieving from my Database.
I want to set the `ImageView` by using the real path (**/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/image.jpg**)

How can this be done?

```
public void getIMG(){
    Cursor res = myDb.GetRow(id);
    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        String path = res.getString(DatabaseHelper.ROWIMG);
        /*img.set'???'*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi try this and see if it helps you

```
 String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            File file = new File(imagePath);
            file.getAbsolutePath();

     BitmapFactory.Options  options =  new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = true ;
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options);

     options.inSampleSize = scaleFactor ;
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false ;
     Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options);
```

Comment: I already have the real path of the image. I am just trying to set the imageView using that path.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to use a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), to have it load the image in the background and apply it to your `ImageView` when the image is ready.

If you are determined to re-invent this wheel yourself, use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` on a background thread to read in the file and give you a `Bitmap` that you can pass to the `ImageView`.